# Removing underline style of autocomplete in react material ui component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to remove the underline style and change the of the color of it when the text field gets focus in the autocomplete component of react material ui.

I can't seem to find the style to override.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the link or code?

Comment: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete

Have a look at the simple example.. I don't want that underline on the textfield.. Rather i want to use my own custom style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `<TextField/>` props that are rendered to the `<AutoComplete/>` component. Because `<AutoComplete />` uses the `<TextField/>` you have access to those props. So you actually have two ways of removing the underline of the autocomplete. Unfortunately this is undocumented in the Material-UI docs for autocomplete.

`<AutoComplete underlineStyle={{display: 'none'}}>`

or

`<AutoComplete underlineShow={false}>`

edit: This answer is relevant to older versions of Material UI. This answer does not work for version 1.0 or higher.

Comment: this is probably for an old material-ui version, refer to @Liem answer

Answer (score 34):

Minor update to @Liem's response. Just putting the `InputProps` directly overwrites the `InputProps` it would use by default, which breaks the component. By merging the `disableUnderline` with the other `InputProps`, it should work.

```
<Autocomplete
   renderInput={
     params => 
       <TextField 
         {...params} 
         InputProps={{...params.InputProps, disableUnderline: true}}
       />
   }
 />
```

Comment: Thank you!  This should be the accepted answer as of Material-UI v4.9.11

Comment: This '...params.InputProps' was what I was missing from other answers. Thx!

Comment: This worked, the key point is that I needed to pass the ...params.InputProps to the InputProps property. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 18):

Just adding another answer for material v1. In v1 we have to target the input inside the text field. in order to remove or style the underline

```
<TextField       
    defaultValue="hello"       
    InputProps={{
       disableUnderline: true
    }}
/>
```