# how to remove the underline of material-ui select?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to remove the underline of Material UI Select list on hovering.

I tried https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-rubin-6x9po?file=/src/Dropdown.jsx which removes the underline by default but when hovered, the underline still shown

i referred [How to change Material UI input underline colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620393/how-to-change-material-ui-input-underline-colour) and [Removing underline style of autocomplete in react material ui component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736198/removing-underline-style-of-autocomplete-in-react-material-ui-component) but both dealt with how to show, I entirely want to remove the underline from select list. Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add the `disableUnderline` prop to `Select`. Here's a modified version of your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/disable-underline-xulxq?file=/src/Dropdown.jsx.

Related answers:

- [How can I remove the underline of TextField from Material-UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914368/how-can-i-remove-the-underline-of-textfield-from-material-ui/61185770#61185770)
- [How to override styles for material-ui TextField component without using the MUIThemeProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436542/how-to-override-styles-for-material-ui-textfield-component-without-using-the-mui/50437531#50437531)

Comment: This prop appears to have been removed from v5 documentation, although it still appears to work. I wonder what the suggested approach is for v5?

Comment: @dmarr The props of the input are also supported. `disableUnderline` is one of the props for [Input](https://mui.com/api/input/).

Answer (score 16):

just add the `disableUnderline` prop to select component, you will no longer see the border-bottom:

```
<Select
    labelId='demo-simple-select-label'
    id='demo-simple-select'
    value={user.status}
    classes={{
        root: classes.selectControl,
        icon: classes.arrowDownIcon,
    }}
    disableUnderline
> 
   ...
</Select>;
```

Comment: This is just a duplicate of accepted answer